# Firefox doesn't set document.referrer despite the correct referrer-policy

Tags: firefox, privacy, referrer

I have a problem with Firefox not setting `document.referrer` property even though the referrer-policy is set in `strict-origin-when-cross-origin`. All other browsers (I checked Chrome, Safari and Edge) set this property correctly (in origin, i.e. https://google.com).
Steps to reproduce:

- open https://www.weltbild.de/
- click any link on the page
- check `document.referrer` in console

  - it's set in 'https://www.weltbild.de/' in Chrome, Edge, and Safari
  - it's empty in Firefox (I'm using fresh installation of 114.0.2 (64-bit) version)